# Enhance an existing Web Project with Datatables

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I am attempting to add the DataTables framework to this existing sample project. The project contains an html file and Javascript file as the front end and a java servlet that talks to a MySQL database as the back end. The Java file retrieves the information from the database and sends a JSON array to the javascript file to actually fill up the table. The html file serves as a skeleton(This is my understanding anyway, correct me if it is wrong please). Currently I can get the datatable to show up and the initial data, but the formatting is off and as soon as I try to sort the table the data disappears.

**This is what it looks like when I load up for the first time**

[image]

**After I try to sort or change the number of entries**

[image]

I have added the needed function call below in the html like many of the basic examples show.

```html
 $(document).ready( function () {
      $('#example').DataTable();
     
        console.log("In ready function");
    } );
```

What I think is happening is it is failing to run the javascript file again after I try to sort. I have tried adding the call to the javascript file and/or followed other examples online but nothing is working. I am new to javascript and JQuery but I feel like this could be fixed by changing where and/or how I call the datatables function. Any help would be greatly appreciated. I put the entire html and javascript files below. As mentioned earlier, the Java file just sends a JSON array to the Js file.

```html
<!-- This example is following frontend and backend separation.

    This .html performs two steps:
    1. Create a html template skeleton, with all the elements defined (some left empty) and named with ids.
    2. Load index.js to populate the data into empty elements.
    -->

<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<!-- Required meta tags -->
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport"
 content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

<!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"
 href="https://cdn.datatables.net/v/bs4-4.0.0/jq-3.2.1/dt-1.10.16/datatables.min.css" />
<script type="text/javascript"
 src="https://cdn.datatables.net/v/bs4-4.0.0/jq-3.2.1/dt-1.10.16/datatables.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
    $(document).ready( function () {
      $('#example').DataTable();
     
        console.log("In ready function");
    } );
  </script>
<title>Star List</title>
</head>
<body>


 <h1>stars</h1>

 <!-- Id "star_table" is useful for jQuery to find the html element with id, class here is mapping to Bootstrap defined class CSS -->
 <table id=star_table class="display">
  <!-- Create a table header -->
  <thead>
   <tr>
    <!-- Titles of each column-->
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>Birth Year</th>
   </tr>
  </thead>
  <!-- Table body is left empty here, will be populated with the data retrieved with index.js -->
  <!-- Again, id "star_table_body" is useful for jQuery to find this html element -->
  <tbody id=star_table_body></tbody>
 </table>

 <!-- Load jQuery and Bootstrap JS -->




 <!-- Load our own JS file -->
 <!-- The path is relative to index.html, since these two files are in the same directory -->
 <!-- Note the url does not contain a "/" in the beginning, which means the url is relative to current path
     otherwise the url is relative to the root path-->
 <script src="index.js"></script>
</body>


</html>
```

```js
/**
 * This example is following frontend and backend separation.
 *
 * Before this .js is loaded, the html skeleton is created.
 *
 * This .js performs two steps:
 *      1. Use jQuery to talk to backend API to get the json data.
 *      2. Populate the data to correct html elements.
 */


/**
 * Handles the data returned by the API, read the jsonObject and populate data into html elements
 * @param resultData jsonObject
 */
function handleStarResult(resultData) {
    console.log("handleStarResult: populating star table from resultData");
    $('#star_table').DataTable();
    // Populate the star table
    // Find the empty table body by id "star_table_body"
    let starTableBodyElement = jQuery("#star_table_body");

    // Iterate through resultData, no more than 10 entries
    for (let i = 0; i < Math.min(10, resultData.length); i++) {

        // Concatenate the html tags with resultData jsonObject
        let rowHTML = "";
        rowHTML += "<tr>";
        rowHTML +=
            "<th>" +
            // Add a link to single-star.html with id passed with GET url parameter
            '<a href="single-star.html?id=' + resultData[i]['star_id'] + '">'
            + resultData[i]["star_name"] +     // display star_name for the link text
            '</a>' +
            "</th>";
        rowHTML += "<th>" + resultData[i]["star_dob"] + "</th>";
        rowHTML += "</tr>";

        // Append the row created to the table body, which will refresh the page
        starTableBodyElement.append(rowHTML);
    }
}




/**
 * Once this .js is loaded, following scripts will be executed by the browser
 */

// Makes the HTTP GET request and registers on success callback function handleStarResult
jQuery.ajax({
    dataType: "json", // Setting return data type
    method: "GET", // Setting request method
    url: "api/stars", // Setting request url, which is mapped by StarsServlet in Stars.java
    success: (resultData) => handleStarResult(resultData) // Setting callback function to handle data returned successfully by the StarsServlet
});
```

```
import com.google.gson.JsonArray;
import com.google.gson.JsonObject;

import javax.annotation.Resource;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import javax.sql.DataSource;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.Statement;


// Declaring a WebServlet called StarsServlet, which maps to url "/api/stars"
@WebServlet(name = "StarsServlet", urlPatterns = "/api/stars")
public class StarsServlet extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    // Create a dataSource which registered in web.xml
    @Resource(name = "jdbc/moviedb")
    private DataSource dataSource;

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
     */
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

        response.setContentType("application/json"); // Response mime type

        // Output stream to STDOUT
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();

        try {
            // Get a connection from dataSource
            Connection dbcon = dataSource.getConnection();

            // Declare our statement
            Statement statement = dbcon.createStatement();

            String query = "SELECT * from stars";

            // Perform the query
            ResultSet rs = statement.executeQuery(query);

            JsonArray jsonArray = new JsonArray();

            // Iterate through each row of rs
            while (rs.next()) {
                String star_id = rs.getString("id");
                String star_name = rs.getString("name");
                String star_dob = rs.getString("birthYear");

                // Create a JsonObject based on the data we retrieve from rs
                JsonObject jsonObject = new JsonObject();
                jsonObject.addProperty("star_id", star_id);
                jsonObject.addProperty("star_name", star_name);
                jsonObject.addProperty("star_dob", star_dob);

                jsonArray.add(jsonObject);
            }

            // write JSON string to output
            out.write(jsonArray.toString());
            // set response status to 200 (OK)
            response.setStatus(200);

            rs.close();
            statement.close();
            dbcon.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {

            // write error message JSON object to output
            JsonObject jsonObject = new JsonObject();
            jsonObject.addProperty("errorMessage", e.getMessage());
            out.write(jsonObject.toString());

            // set reponse status to 500 (Internal Server Error)
            response.setStatus(500);

        }
        out.close();

    }
}
```

Comment: I'm removing the Java tag because that doesn't seem relevant to the post. If your JSON is improperly formatted and sent to Javascript, then you should include that Java code

Comment: I don't think the JSON is the issue, but I will add the java file just in case.

Comment: Please provide a short extract of your json. Anyway, you miss quotes around your `<table>` an `<tbody>` IDs. You also have multiple datatable initialisations, such as `$('#star_table').DataTable();` and your `$('#example').DataTable();` (which doesn't exists). I cannot see your jquery file included in the page (though I bet it is there somewhere). In your `handleStarResult()` function, you should destroy any table if already init-ed, then add `<tr>` before, and at the end you re-init the datatable